# Computation of kernel matrix using radial basis kernel in svm

Tags: kernel, matrix, rbf

I want to compute a kernel matrix using RBF on my own. The training data is multidimensional. My query is whether we will apply
$$e^{-\gamma(x-y)^2}$$
for each dimension and then sum the values across all dimension?

Answer (score 2):

The kernel matrix $K$ or **Gram Matrix** is a positive-semidefinite symmetric matrix that has the form:
$$ K(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = 
\begin{vmatrix}
\langle x_1,x_1 \rangle & \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle & \dots & \langle x_1,x_n \rangle \\
\langle x_2,x_1 \rangle & \langle x_2,x_2 \rangle & \dots & \langle x_2,x_n \rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
\langle x_n,x_1 \rangle & \langle x_n,x_2 \rangle & \dots & \langle x_n,x_n \rangle 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Where $\langle a,b \rangle$ detones the inner product/dot product of vectors $a$ and $b$ and $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ is a set of vectors (in this case, training samples).

In order to calculate the Gramian Matrix you will have to calculate the Inner Product using the Kernel Function. For a RBF kernel function $\kappa_{RBF}$ this can be done by

$$K_{ij} = \kappa_{RBF}(x_i,x_j) = e^{\gamma D_{ist}(x_i,x_j)^2} $$

where $\gamma$ is a function hyperparameter, $K_{ij}$ is the element in row $i$ and column $j$ of the matrix $K$ and $ D_{ist}(x_i,x_j)$ is some distance between two vector measured in some vector space.

Usually, the distance measure used is the $L_2$ norm or *euclidean distance*. Remember that when computing the Kernel function you will use the square $L_2$ norm, so there is no need to take the square root.

There is a open library named **[pykernels](https://github.com/gmum/pykernels)** that has implementations to dozens of kernel functions. This here is the implementation for the RBF (or Gaussian) Kernel:

```py
class RBF(Kernel):
    """
    Radial Basis Function kernel, defined as unnormalized Gaussian PDF
        K(x, y) = e^(-g||x - y||^2)
    where:
        g = gamma
    """

    def __init__(self, gamma=None):
        self._gamma = gamma

    def _compute(self, data_1, data_2):
        if self._gamma is None:
            # libSVM heuristics
            self._gamma = 1./data_1.shape[1]

        dists_sq = euclidean_dist_matrix(data_1, data_2)
        return np.exp(-self._gamma * dists_sq)

    def dim(self):
        return np.inf
```

it uses the square distance define as:

```py
def euclidean_dist_matrix(data_1, data_2):
    """
    Returns matrix of pairwise, squared Euclidean distances
    """
    norms_1 = (data_1 ** 2).sum(axis=1)
    norms_2 = (data_2 ** 2).sum(axis=1)
    return np.abs(norms_1.reshape(-1, 1) + norms_2 - 2 * np.dot(data_1, data_2.T))
```

The class is defined as a subclass of the Kernel class and has some methods to deal with kernel combinations.

**Note** that this is not the fastest way to implement euclidean distance, you [can do better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370975/python-numpy-euclidean-distance-calculation-between-matrices-of-row-vectors) but this is a simple form to do it. also that "np.abs" should not be needed

**Note 2** that this [SO Question has a lot of optimized version of RBF Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271662/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-an-rbf-kernel-in-python)

Comment: Thank you Pedro for the clarification